# android - data binding to field, displaying matching icon

Tags: android, data-binding, listener, android-broadcastreceiver, android-databinding

I have a class `WifiManager` that holds a Boolean value that represents either **wifi connected** or **wifi disconnected**.

the Boolean field gets updated with a `broadcastReceiver` I have in that class.

```
private BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver;

private boolean isWifiConnected = false;

wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                    // Wifi connected/disconnected
                    NetworkInfo nwInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                    final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    if (nwInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                        // wifi connect
                        isWifiConnected = true;
                    } else {
                        // wifi disconnected
                        isWifiConnected = false;
                    }
                }
        };

        context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, wifiIntentFilter);
```

In my `MainActivity` I have a `WifiManager` field, and what I want is to do **data binding** that will **change one of the menu items based on the Boolean value** -> if `isWifiConnected=false` set icon to `@drawalbe/xxx`, if `isWifiConnected=true` set icon to `@drawalbe/yyy`.

Meaning - having sort of a "listener" to changes of the `isWifiConnected` value, and based on that - set one of the `MenuItem`'s icon to either `@drawalbe/xxx` or `@drawalbe/yyy`.

I know there are tons of ways to do it, from broadcasting an `Intent` in the `BroadcastReceiver` and catch it in the `MainActivity` to just have a `Handler` running and checking the `isWifiConnected` every 3 seconds..

What I am **really** looking for is sort of **data binding** with a converter, like you would do in a **MVVM project**.

Is there such a thing in android?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know about android data binding and you're just asking how to do it for this specific case. If not, here is the [android data binding guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

You will need a way to observe the boolean value so the UI can remain updated. The easiest way is to make it an ObservableBoolean field of your model object:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public final ObservableBoolean isWifiConnected = new ObservableBoolean();
    // other things you want to bind to your layout...
}
```

When you create the binding, you must also assign the model:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    ActivityMainBinding binding =
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    this.model = new ViewModel();
    binding.setModel(this.model);
}
```

And when you receive the broadcast, you update the model:

```
wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        //...
        model.isWifiConnected.set(newValue);
        //...
    };
```

And your layout would be something like this:

```
<layout ...>
    <data>
        <variable name="model" type="com.example.ViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <!-- rest of layout -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@{model.isWifiConnected ? @drawable/xxx : @drawable/yyy}"/>
</layout>
```

You could also avoid the model class if you keep track of the binding and set the variable directly on it. In that case, you'd have a variable:

```
<variable name="isWifiConnected" type="boolean"/>
```

And your broadcast receiver would set the value:

```
binding.setIsWifiConnected(newValue);
```

Comment: I have a question. Do I have to check if model is not null in BroadcastReceiver in method onHandleMessage?